# needing help in windows service

Tags: c#, windows-services

i wrote a windows service but when i installed it i found that it doesn't work.i don't know what is problem!

this service move some file from one place to another place!

i need help

thanks

```
    public partial class Service1 : ServiceBase
    {


        public Service1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
        }
        protected override void OnContinue()
        {
            const string SrcPath = "d:\\Source";
            const string DisPath = "d:\\Dist\\";
            if (Directory.Exists(SrcPath))
            {
                string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(SrcPath);
                for (int i = 0; i < files.Length; i++)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(files[i]);
                    string[] list = files[i].Split('\\');
                    if (!File.Exists(DisPath + list[list.Length - 1]))
                    {
                        File.Move(files[i], DisPath + list[list.Length - 1]);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        protected override void OnStop()
        {
        }
}
```

Comment: no,this is my first service and i don't know anything about that. do you know any reference for learning services?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y817hyb6(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 2):

That's because you aren't doing anything in your `OnStart()` method.  You need to have the logic you want there.  `OnContinue()` is fired when a "Continue" command is fired from the SCM.

[ServiceBase.OnStart() Method Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.servicebase.onstart.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Just to add to what Shark said, I would guess that you don't want this to just do the work one time and then be effectively dead. So you need to have some sort of mechanism to periodically determine if the work needs to be done, then do the work, then wait a bit and repeat.

Otherwise, I would suggest you just look at putting a batch script on the windows task scheduler.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add somthing into your `OnStart`

```
   System.Timers.Timer timer = new System.Timers.Timer();

        protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
            timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(timer_Elapsed);
            timer.Enabled = true;
            timer.Interval = AppSettings.PeriodOfQuering;
        }

        void timer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            DoJob();
        }
```